# How do I databind Tooltips to a GridView bound to a DataTable?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

Helo,

I am trying to add `Tooltips` to a `GridView` bound to a `DataTable`. 
If I use a static text the tooltip works, so I assume that the error must lie in the data binding.

Here my `XAML`:

```
   <TabControl x:Name="MainTabs" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=TabModels}" DisplayMemberPath="TabCaption">
        <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=TabDataTable}" AutoGenerateColumns="True" IsReadOnly="True" SelectionUnit="CellOrRowHeader" >

                    <DataGrid.Resources>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding Path=ColumnDescriptions, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataTemplate}}}"/>
                                </Trigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </DataGrid.Resources> 

                </DataGrid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
    </TabControl>
```

And here is my custom class `TabModel`:

```
public ObservableCollection<TabModel> TabModels { get; set; }    
public class TabModel
        {
            public string Title { get; set; }
            public string TabCaption { get; set; }
            public DataTable TabDataTable { get; set; }
            public ObservableCollection<String> ColumnDescriptions { get; set;}
        }
```

Could someone please tell me how the `Databinding` needs to be done correctly?

Comment: at first glance it looks like the problem is that your trying to bind to the data template, you need to bind to either a control on the template or preferably to the data the template is hosting

Comment: @Sinatr The tooltip doesnt work at all, however if I use a static string eg Value="Tooltip" than it works.

Comment: @Sinatr `DataGridItem` and `GridItem` result in a not supported in WPF Error, and with `DataGridColumn` or `DataGridRow` the Tooltips still don't show up.

Comment: If you `FindAncestor` of `TabItem` type, then this `TabItem.DataContext` should be the actual tab `TabModel`. Easy so far. But then you have a problem: how to get corresponding to mouse-hovered column item from `ColumnDescriptions` collection. Doesn't looks easy, perhaps a converter in which you can identify column index and return corresponding `ColumnDescription[column]` value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an [IMultiValueConverter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3980174/4838058).

```
<DataGrid.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
        <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="ToolTip">
            <Setter.Value>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource IndexToDescriptionConverter}">
                    <Binding Path="Column.DisplayIndex" 
                             RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}"/>
                    <Binding Path="DataContext.ColumnDescriptions" 
                             RelativeSource="{RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}"/>
                </MultiBinding>
            </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.Resources>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This solved my Problem. Just a last question when I change Tabs from my TabControl a `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` gets thrown and the Index is -1. For now I fixed it with a try catch block. But that doesnt seem like such a clean solution to me. Maybe an if statement to ignore -1? Any Ideas?

Comment: You can handle the -1 in the converter. Returning an empty string, instead of trying to get the element at the given index.

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to post my working code for anyone with the same problem:

`XAML`:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:IndexToDescriptionConverter x:Key="IndexToDescriptionConverter" />
</Window.Resources> 
....
    <TabControl x:Name="MainTabs" Grid.Row="2" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=TabModels}" DisplayMemberPath="TabCaption">
        <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=TabDataTable}" AutoGenerateColumns="True" IsReadOnly="True" SelectionUnit="CellOrRowHeader" >
                    <DataGrid.Resources>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="ToolTip">
                                        <Setter.Value>
                                            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource IndexToDescriptionConverter}">
                                                <Binding Path="Column.DisplayIndex" 
                         RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}"/>
                                                <Binding Path="DataContext.ColumnDescriptions" 
                         RelativeSource="{RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}"/>
                                            </MultiBinding>
                                        </Setter.Value>
                                    </Setter>
                                </Trigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </DataGrid.Resources>
                </DataGrid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
    </TabControl>
```

My Custom Class `TabModel`:

```
 public class TabModel
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string TabCaption { get; set; }
        public DataTable TabDataTable { get; set; }
        public ObservableCollection<String> ColumnDescriptions { get; set; }
    }
```

And the `IMultiValueConverter`:

```
public class IndexToDescriptionConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        int index = (int)values[0];
        if(index < 0)
        {
            return null;
        }
        ObservableCollection<String> ColumnDescriptions = (ObservableCollection<String>)values[1];
        return ColumnDescriptions.ElementAt(index);
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Thanks to everyone who took their time and helped with this.