# Xaml multi-bind ToolTip

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a `DataGrid` with list of DataRows as its `ItemSource`. I want each cell to have a `ToolTip` of 2 `DataCell` values, so I'm using a MultiBinding on the `ToolTipService.ToolTip` object. The Converter returns the currect data (as a string), but the `ToolTip` shows the system name of the `TextBlock`. I'm trying to do what is in [here](http://www.gdomc.com/0502/wpf-tooltip-with-multibinding/), but the result is the same: it returns the `TextBlock` system name but not the value that I'm expecting.

Any idea what I'm missing?

Thanks in advance.

The XAML:

```xml
<TextBlock Padding="5,0,5,0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"                                                      
Text="{Binding Path=[1][cell_value], Converter={StaticResource Converter1}}" FlowDirection="LeftToRight">
<ToolTipService.ToolTip>
    <TextBlock>
        <TextBlock.Text>
            <MultiBinding StringFormat="F {0}{1}" Converter="{StaticResource Converter2}">
                <Binding Path="[1][updted_by]" />
                <Binding Path="[1][v_date]" />
            </MultiBinding>
        </TextBlock.Text>
    </TextBlock>
</ToolTipService.ToolTip>
```

The converter:

```cs
public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
{
    try
    {
        int v = 0;
        if (values[0] == null)
            return string.Empty;

        int.TryParse(values[0].ToString(), out v);
        if (v < 1)
            return string.Empty;

        string result1 = string.Empty;
        string result2 = string.Empty;

        result1 = ManageBL.GetUserNameStringById((int)values[0]);

        // now convert the date
        if (values[1] == null || values[1] == DBNull.Value)
            return Binding.DoNothing;

        DateTime dt = DateTime.MinValue;
        DateTime.TryParse(values[1].ToString(), out dt);

        if (dt == DateTime.MinValue || dt == DateTime.Parse("01/01/1900"))
        {
            return null;
        }

        result2 = dt.ToShortDateString();

        return result1 + result2;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return Binding.DoNothing;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting the MultiBinding as the Tooltip value directly

```
<ToolTipService.ToolTip>
    <MultiBinding StringFormat="F {0}{1}" Converter="{StaticResource Converter2}">
        <Binding Path="[1][updted_by]" />
        <Binding Path="[1][v_date]" />
    </MultiBinding>
</ToolTipService.ToolTip>
```

As per [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37793535/4838058).