# Provide bound paramaters to styles

Tags: wpf, xaml, staticresource

I have a style that I am reusing a lot. Some parts of it are static, and so I create a style resource for these (called "BorderCell"), but for visibility, the binding for this is meant to change for each element.

Currently I am having to apply this same style to many of my border's:

```
<Border.Style>
    <Style TargetType="Border" BasedOn="{StaticResource BorderCell}">
        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="{Binding DataContext.Toggles.Group, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Group}" Value="{x:Null}">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Border.Style>
```

Where I replace the bindings each time to different properties.

How would I go about creating a style that I could simply reference by calling `<border style="{StaticResource Foo}" />`, where I can provide a couple parameters for the style to use - in this case I would provide DataContext.Toggles.Group and Group as 2 different parameters for it, so it can sort out the triggers for visibility?

Comment: Could you forego the style and bind to the Visibility property of the Border directly?

Comment: @andrew I'm not entirely sure what you mean. I am needing to set the visibility of the border based on the value of a boolean being true or false, which is the first setter in the code snippet, but also I want to override that to set the visibility to collapsed if a seperate binding is null. Each time I use the style though, both these bindings are different. how would I bind to the border visibility through the style to achieve that?

Comment: Sorry I overlooked the crux of your question being the two parameters. I suppose you could use a custom `IMultiValueConverter` and a MultiBinding the XAML (as seen in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3980039/wpf-ivalueconverter-converting-multiple-values-into-a-single-value) question). Though, that starts to be as verbose as (and probably less readable than) your original style trigger.